# How can I send an array of arrays with android's httppost

Tags: android, http-post

I would like to send an array of arrays from an android phone to a server. Is there any possibility to do this?

I expect something like this at the server side:

```
$_POST['items'] = array(
    array('name'=>'joe', 'email'=>'joe@example.com'), 
    array('name'=>'jane', 'email'=>'jane@example.com')
);
```

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpPost` to send data to the server, and use `json` to create an array of array's. `nameValuePairs` will carry the data:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);         
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items", jsonObject));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Hope this helps...